# String Format вывести значение

Tags: c#, строки, format

```
       PointPair point = curve[iPt];
    string StringPointValue = string.Format("X:{0} \nY: {1:F4}", point.X, point.Y);
    return StringPointValue;
```

Суть этого, при наводке мышью на точкой оно выводит точку. Так вот числа показывает, но если это число больше чем 2 то выводит нули, почему ?

Comment: ну строка форматирования положим правильная. Для `X:{0}` должно вывести все, без округления, для `Y:{1:F4}` должно вывести значение с 4 знаками после запятой. А вот что за контрол вы используете, что за класс `PointPair` и что это WinForms или WPF?

Answer (score 1):

Что будет выводить если вместо:

```
string StringPointValue = string.Format("X:{0} \nY: {1:F4}", point.X, point.Y);
```

поставить:

```
string StringPointValue = string.Format("X: {0,2:F4} \nY: {1,2:F4}", point.X, point.Y);
```

?

Должно выводить:

```
X: 02,5354
Y: 12,1234
```

А вообще, лучше бросить на это значение trace...